# Word order question with question tag: broke/bottles/did't they/those

Tags: tag-questions

> 1) broke/bottles/did't they/those

I need to order the words to make questions with question tags Please, help me to make a correct question with question tag. I didn't find an answer. And it means I don't know how to form a question using these words.

Comment: Olga, we don't do homework for people. Also, we say: I'm learning English as a second language. And: didn't. You might want to go and read the help section (upper right on your screen) first.

Comment: You should still [edit] your post to include your best attempt and why you think it’s wrong, as we typically ask for your own research. Otherwise, your question may be closed.